# setInterval won't get out of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following javascript code takes randomly selected value from a array and types it in the input box. I've used jquery. I want to end setInterval "zaman2", so after It ends I can retype the next random string to the input box. But the loop doesn't end and gets stuck. How can I solve this?
Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AQbq4/4/

```
var dersler = [...very long list...];
var zaman = setTimeout(function() {
    var yeniDers = dersler[Math.floor(Math.random()*dersler.length)];
    sayac = 0;
    var zaman2 = setInterval(function() {
            var harf = yeniDers.slice(0,(sayac+1));
            sayac++;
            $('#main-search').attr('placeholder', harf).typeahead({source: dersler});
        if (sayac == yeniDers.length) {
            clearInterval(zaman2);
        }
    },450);
},2000);
```

Comment: You probably want `setTimeout` for that as well?

Comment: Nope, I want to get rid of `setInterval`

Comment: It's hard to tell what `yeniDers` is, but are you sure you don't want `sayac >= yeniDirs.length`?

Comment: `yeniDers` is the randomly selected value from the array. When `sayac == yeniDirs.length` the loop should stop.

Comment: What are the values of dersler?

Comment: If I move `sayac` outside the `setInterval` loop, the value of `sayac` will never reach the value of `yeniDers` and the loop will contiue forever.

Comment: What is the comma after the array doing?

Comment: @mplungjan The comma was a mistake.

Comment: @THEtheChad you can find the values in the jsFiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you mean

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rUd3Y/)

```
var tId, tId2;
function show() {
    var ran = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
    cnt = 0;
    tId = setInterval(function() {
            var char = ran.slice(0,(cnt+1));
            cnt++;
            $( '#main-search' ).attr('placeholder', char);
        if (cnt == ran.length) {
            clearInterval(tId);
            tId2=setTimeout(show,2000);
        }
    },450);
}
show();
```